# wrapper for a multitude of functions to check for existing data

Tags: python, python-decorators

If it is so, please do not hesitate to close question as duplicate. :)

In my code, I have a lot of blocks that look like

```
try:
    load_from_disk(pathtofile)
except IOError:
    datapiece = comp_this_data( **dictofargs )
    save_to_disk(pathtofile, datapiece)
```

**Question:** How to define a routine that takes care of possible precomputed data for different `comp_this_data`?

Maybe, this is an easy case for python decorators. However, as I understood, the decorator is part of the function definition, which I don't want to change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you can wrap multiple computation functions:

```
def compute_and_save(compute_f, file, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        load_from_disk(file)
    except IOError:
        datapiece = compute_f(*args, **kwargs)
        save_to_disk(file, datapiece)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    compute_and_save(comp_this_data, file, **dictofargs)
    compute_and_save(comp_this_data_2, file, **dictofargs)
```

Comment: How does this answer "[take] care of possible precomputed data for different `comp_this_data`"?

Comment: Well, it does in so far as you can pass different `comp_this_data` to it.

Comment: From OP's code, it looks like the computed data is stored in a file. If the file is not present (i.e. we get IOError), we assume that it needs to be computed again.